# Keyword still be executed even the condition is false on robot framework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, selenium2library

```
${result}   get location
Do some click so the link will not same
${elem}     get location

Verify
run keyword unless  '${result}' == '${elem}'    keywordA
run keyword if      '${result}' == '${elem}'    keywordB
```

I have this example code on robot framework 
I want to run the 
keywordA if > condition false 
and run keywordB if > condition true

But however, if the condition false, the keywordA will executed, but keywordB as well.
Anyone can help with solutions? Thanks

basically I want if else statement like

```
if(condition true) { run B }
 else { run A }
```

Comment: Can you add the `Get Location` Keyword code and the value that is stored in `${result}`. Without these two it won't be possible to provide a good answer.

Comment: hi @A.Kootstra Get Location is builtin keyword, isn't it?  
and the ${result} and ${elem} both stored link url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) accepts an ELSE clause

```
Run keyword if  '${result}' == '${elem}'  
...  keywordB
...  ELSE
...  keywordA
```

Here's a complete working example:

```
*** Keywords ***
keywordA
    log to console   \nthis is keyword A

keywordB
    log to console   \nthis is keyword B

*** Variables ***
${result}  foo
${elem}    foo

*** Test Cases ***
test case A
    Run keyword if  '${result}' == '${elem}'  
    ...  keywordB
    ...  ELSE
    ...  keywordA
```

Comment: hi @Bryan Oakley  I used your syntax, but it returns error 

Keyword 'BuiltIn.Run Keyword If' expected at least 2 arguments, got 1.

Comment: @Lutfi: then you did something wrong. I can literally cut and paste my answer into a test case where I've defined `${result}` and `${elem}`, along with `keywordA` and `keywordB`, and it worked fine.

Comment: it solved, 
the keywordB should one line with Run keyword if  '${result}' == '${elem}'  
Thanks @Bryan